# 300GB of phantom data on my Samsung 970 EVO M.2 and no option to format: Is there anything else I can do?

Tags: ssd, formatting, m.2, samsung-ssd

### The problem:

So something really weird is going on with my Samsung 970 EVO M.2 SSD. Opening the drive and ensuring hidden files are shown, it's empty:

[image]

but looking in the properties panel it's also not:

[image: drive properties]

So time to try all tools available to figure this out, starting with the basics:

### Debugging steps so far:

**1. Disk Cleanup**

[image]

Nothing to gain.

**2. Optimize and Defragment**

[image]

It was worth a shot but no dice.

[image]

**3. Error Checking**

[image]

[image]

Hmm, that's a lot of scanning for a drive you're so sure is empty Windows...

[image]

Nothing to see here.

**4. Format Drive**

If all else fails, let's just format the dang thing... Right?

[image]

Wrong.

**5. Samsung Magician**

Alright no luck yet, but it's a Samsung drive, so surely if anything can figure this out it'd be a Samsung drive management tool.

[image]

[image]

Alrighty then. Apparently Samsung doesn't fully support this product they sold me. EDIT: According to the rep, since M.2 was such a new product, the first version of the 970 EVO didn't support Diagnostic Scan, but the next gen of the same drive does support it.

**6. Called Samsung**

The tech noticed Disk Manager shows that the drive is listed as a pagefile. Now that I think about it, I do think I recall using some setting to let my other drives be used as page-files for memory because I was running a simulation program that needed massive memory space. But I dont recall what the setting was or where I found it

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: This question would look a lot better if I had the rep to post it properly, sorry

Comment: If the drive is a pagefile, you can remove it. https://www.technobezz.com/how-to-remove-pagefile-sys-in-windows-10/   If this fails, I would (carefully) boot up a Linux distro and repartition/reformat the disk outside Windows.

Comment: @davidgo beat ya to it! See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue!

I had wandered into Windows advanced system settings and found how to set pagefile allocation on other drives. It was a long time ago and I never noticed until now.

Here's a guide to do (and undo) this:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-move-virtual-memory-different-drive-windows-10

Settings > System > About > Related Settings / System Info > Advanced System Settings > Performance > Settings > Advanced